# Imagick Not Loaded in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagick, pecl

I have installed Imagick on Ubuntu 12.04 but still i get

> Class 'Imagick' not found

When I check through terminal

> php -m

I get

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

but when i check loaded extension through PHP script

> get_loaded_extensions()

I am not getting imagick

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => sqlite3
    [7] => zlib
    [8] => bcmath
    [9] => bz2
    [10] => calendar
    [11] => ctype
    [12] => curl
    [13] => dba
    [14] => dom
    [15] => hash
    [16] => fileinfo
    [17] => filter
    [18] => ftp
    [19] => gd
    [20] => gettext
    [21] => SPL
    [22] => iconv
    [23] => session
    [24] => intl
    [25] => json
    [26] => ldap
    [27] => mbstring
    [28] => mcrypt
    [29] => mssql
    [30] => standard
    [31] => mysqlnd
    [32] => mysqli
    [33] => mysql
    [34] => PDO
    [35] => pdo_mysql
    [36] => pdo_pgsql
    [37] => pdo_sqlite
    [38] => Phar
    [39] => posix
    [40] => Reflection
    [41] => imap
    [42] => shmop
    [43] => SimpleXML
    [44] => soap
    [45] => sockets
    [46] => exif
    [47] => sybase_ct
    [48] => sysvsem
    [49] => sysvshm
    [50] => tokenizer
    [51] => wddx
    [52] => xml
    [53] => xmlreader
    [54] => xmlwriter
    [55] => xsl
    [56] => zip
    [57] => apache2handler
    [58] => mhash
)
```

php -i displays

```
imagick 

module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.2.0RC1
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2012-08-17
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 206
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, A, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BGRA, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, C, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, J2C, JNG, JP2, JPC, JPEG, JPG, JPX, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
```

getting this error in PHP log

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
```

Comment: Your also run the code through terminal?

Comment: Have you restarted the web server?

Comment: Probably you haven't altered your `php.ini`

Comment: I have altered php.ini and added "extension=imagick.so" and also restarted web server but no change.

Comment: I am using XAMPP 1.8.3 (PHP 5.5.6). .so file is placed in /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/Imagick.so

Comment: can you provide php code that results in "class imagick not found" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Possible solution:

Double check the paths and php configuration - you might have the imagick.so file in another directory, not the one php is looking for extensions in ?

1) Locate the proper php.ini file - in your phpinfo() page it is pointed which php.ini is actually in use.

2) Make sure you have imagick.so in proper extension dir (the one php really uses). To check the actual path use:

> php-config --extension-dir

3) if (1) and (2) are OK, enable the extension in php.ini

> extension=imagick.so

4) restart web server, the imagick should be present (loaded) in phpinfo()

### Remark #1

[SO source post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860043/2596503)

Bear in mind that the following also apply

> Your extension should compatible with your PHP server in three main
>   attributes:
>
> 1- The Zend API number which your PHP server is configured with ( in
>   phpinfo() you can find this number), this number should be the same
>   with your extension header file at build time.
>
> 2- The compiler version on your PHP server and your extension must be
>   the same.
>
> 3- Thread safety in your PHP server is important. If you use
>   thread-safe server then your extension must be built with php
>   thread-safe library and if you use non-thread safe server you should
>   build your extension with PHP-nts library.

### Remark #2

[SO source post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158047/2596503)

Keep in mind that if an .so file is corrupt, is improper in other ways (incorrect file structure) or depends on files that are missing or not available for load - the extension will not be loaded and made available.

### Remark #3

Note that the "php -m" shows modules compiled into php, not the loaded extensions. Try the below for more detailed information:

> php -i

### EDIT

The provided php error

> Module compiled with module API=20090626 
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20121212

clearly indicates that you have the module compiled with improper API version that does not match the php. **You will need to build the PHP extension manually.** The extension you've ended up with seems to be built against a different version of PHP, not your current PHP 5.5.

There are numerous tutorials concerning this topic, just remember to use the proper version of imagick and phpize. This should help you out: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/ImageMagick_and_imagick_php_module_on_shared_hosting

Comment: Still i am facing the same issue. php.ini not loading imagick extension

Comment: did you check the extension path ?

Comment: I am not sure weather i am using php thread-safe library or not as well as not sure about extension also that it is thread-safe or not. Can you please tell me how to check it?

Comment: yeah i did check path, and its the same

Comment: how did you install imagick in the first place ? did you do "sudo apt-get install imagemagick" first and than "sudo apt-get install php5-imagick" ?

Comment: check out this post for thread safety http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php

Comment: If i had safe thread issue, i dont think i would get reply from php -i as imagick enabled

Comment: Is imagick present in phpinfo at all ? If still no luck, check apache error log for any related errors, maybe you will find some usefull info (like "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ...")

Comment: phpize -v shows
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626

Comment: @MustafaMansoor you should accept and +1 the answer as it pins down the exact cause of your problem. For a further solution you can try the suggested tutorial or you need to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Restart php

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had it installed in the Docker container, but I was running my CLI script from the host machine, which didn't have Imagick.