# imagick not shown in phpinfo

Tags: php, imagick

I have imagick installed in my webserver. And when I do a php -m | grep imagick, I do see that it's there:

```
[root@uszwslp00031la ~]# php -m | grep imagick
imagick
```

However when I look in the phpinfo page for the server, I don't see that imagick is loaded. So does that mean that imagick is not actually working, even tho I see it on the command line?

I have the extension loaded in my php.ini file:

```
[root@uszwslp00031la ~]# php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini

 [root@uszwslp00031la ~]# grep imagick.so /etc/php.ini
extension = imagick.so
```

And the extension file is loaded in the right extension directory:

```
[root@uszwslp00031la ~]# php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226 => /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226

[root@uszwslp00031la ~]# ls -l /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/imagick.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1154336 Jun 28 20:07 /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/imagick.so
```

So like I asked, is this working or not? How can I be sure. And if need to get the imagick extension to show up in the phpinfo page, how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error log? I know awhile back when I was messing with `ImageMagick` it turned out to be an incompatible compilation error, so it was not actually loading the module even though it wasn't there.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is available? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208253/verify-imagemagick-installation. If it is installed correctly and available it should be visible on phpinfo()

Comment: Same problem. php -m | grep imagick show imagick correctly, but my phpinfo() doesn't. I write in my php.ini: extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56-imagick/3.3.0_2/imagick.so

Comment: sorry for late reply.. this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991140/imagick-not-loaded-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just my two cents, after couple of hours of banging my head against the server (Amazon Linux 2)... I had installed imagick:

```
sudo yum install php-imagick
```

And restarted apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

But the phpinfo still would not list the module...

What I had to do to get the ball rolling:

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```