# No oci8 module in phpinfo()

Tags: php, oracle

I try to set up connection with oracle database, but I still can't even set up the module. I have rhel 7. 2 server, and I followed whole tutorial for setting up oracle instantclient and configured it with php. One thing I completely don't understand is that oci8 module displays after `php -i` execution:

```
oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.1.3
Revision => $Id: 59f993160cf983dd24bb391b68a65a17303d2dba $
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 12.1.0.2.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 12.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.events => Off => Off
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
```

But there is no such module in phpinfo() inside the script. How to fix it?

PHP Version 7.0.13
Server Apache (httpd)

LD library path:
[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: There are separate configurations for CLI and your web environment ... It's quite possible that you've only enabled the module under CLI.

Comment: @Narf I included driver extention into ini file, what else have to be done?

Comment: Find the correct php.ini for your httpd (that's probably shown by `phpinfo()`) and add it there.

Comment: @Narf they are absolutely the same, to check it I included external ini file with oci8 extention line, and this config was loaded in phpinfo(). But module still does not appear as a section

Comment: Well, do you have the `oci8_*()` functions available? If so, I wouldn't care if something appears in `phpinfo()` ... maybe I got the question wrong. Either way, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The common problem would be that LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't set for Apache.
Try adding it to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` like:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/to/oracle-client`

If I have my versions right, this version of Apache (i) doesn't like the `export` keyword for setting variables (ii) requires a full path since it won't expand environment variables.  If I'm wrong, try either or both of those.

There is a lot of information about setting the environment in the free [Underground Oracle & PHP Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html), see, for example 'Setting Oracle Environment Variables for Apache' on p 108

You say you followed 'whole tutorial'.  There are many tutorials.  I'd recommend [Oracle's installation instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html).

Comment: I pasted this variable, and used tutorial was the official one (which you provided)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

## setsebool -P allow_execstack 1

You also can enable executable stack for only oci8.so with:

## execstack -c /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so

https://serverfault.com/questions/314336/centos-6-php-can-not-load-gdchart-so-and-oci8-so-compiled-by-me

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the oci8.so is in the php extension folder

in centos is  `/usr/lib64/php/modules`
in ubuntu xammp is  `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718`

```
cd  <extension folder >
sudo chmod 755 oci8.so
```

It works for me after

```
 ps ax | grep "fpm"
```

check the **pid** of "php-fpm: master process"

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

start php-fpm again

```
sudo service php-fpm start
```

inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693610/2538630